# jQuery .ajax call not returning data

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to update my HTML UI with data returned from a server running on an embedded system (means I have full control over what is returned).  The data callback in the .ajax function never seems to be called however, why would this be?

The jQuery code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pollGps').click(function() {
        alert('calling /pollgps.json'); 
        $.ajax({
            url: '/pollgps.json',
            dataType:'json',
            success: function( data ) {
                alert('success ' + JSON.stringify(data));
                $("#settingId").html(data.settingId);
                $("#settingValue").html(data.settingValue);
            }
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error polling GPS ' + textStatus);
            }
        });
    });
})
```

and the server response is

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
"settingId"="CFG-NAV2",
"settingValue"="0xdead"
}
```

Comment: Did you try to stringify your data before alerting it or simply logging it to the console to see what's there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not valid JSON

```
{
    "settingId"="CFG-NAV2",
    "settingValue"="0xdead"
}
```

The following is

```
{
    "settingId" : "CFG-NAV2",
    "settingValue" : "0xdead"
}
```

Get familiar with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: Thanks, am generating the JSON by hand so a little error prone.  Got it working now.